# Inserting two elements in node template in a doubly linked list

Tags: c++

I'm new with data structures in C++, and i'm trying to do a doubly linked list with templates. All the examples that i have seen are only for 1 element of the template node, so i'm trying to put 2 elements in the template node in the list, but i don't know how to do it, anyway, i tried to make the list.

Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

template<class T>

// node class
class node
{
public:
     node();
     node(T);
     ~node();

    node *next;
    T data[2];

    void borra_todo();
    void print();
};

// by defect
template<typename T>
node<T>::node()
{
    data[0] = NULL;
    data[1] = NULL;
    next = NULL;
}

// by parameter
template<typename T>
node<T>::node(T data_)
{
    data[0] = data_[0];
    data[1] = data_[1];
    next = NULL;
}

// delete nodes
template<typename T>
void node<T>::borra_todo()
{
  if (next) 
  next->borra_todo();

  delete this;
}

// node printing
template<typename T>
void node<T>::print()
{
    cout << data[0] << " " << data[1] <<  "->";
}

template<typename T>
node<T>::~node() {}

// list

template <class T>
class list
{
 private:
        node<T> *m_head;
        int m_num_nodes;

 public:
        list();
        ~list();

        void add_head(T);
        void add_end(T);
        void add_sort(T);
        void fill(char r[30],  char n[30]);
        void search(T);
        void del_by_data(T);
        void print();
};

template<typename T>
list<T>::list()
{
   m_num_nodes = 0;
   m_head = NULL;
}

//add in the beginning
template<typename T>
void list<T>::add_head(T data_)
{
   node<T> *new_node = new node<T>(data_);
   node<T> *temp = m_head;

   if (!m_head)
   {
       m_head = new_node;
   }
   else
   {
       new_node->next = m_head;
       m_head = new_node;

       while (temp)
       {
              temp = temp->next;
       }
   }
   m_num_nodes++;
}

// add to the last
template<typename T>
void list<T>::add_end(T data_)
{
   node<T> *new_node = new node<T> (data_);
   node<T> *temp = m_head;

   if (!m_head)
   { 
       m_head = new_node;
   }
   else
   {
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
              temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = new_node;
   }
   m_num_nodes++;
}

// it is supposed that sorts items in the list ...
template<typename T>
void list<T>::add_sort(T data_)
{
   node<T> *new_node = new node<T> (data_);
   node<T> *temp = m_head;

   if (!m_head)
   {
       m_head = new_node;
   }
   else
   {
       for (int i =0; i <= 1; i++)
       {

           if (m_head->data[0] > data_[i])
           {
                 new_node->next = m_head;
                 m_head = new_node;
           } 
           else
           {
                while ((temp->next != NULL) && (temp->next->data[0] < data_[i]))
                {
                      temp = temp->next;
                }
                new_node->next = temp->next;
                temp->next = new_node;
           }
       }
   m_num_nodes++;
   }
}

// sort adding ...
template<typename T>
void list<T>::fill(char rfc[30])
{
  char temprfc[30];
  char tempnombre[30];

  temprfc = "DUDE010101R0";
  tempnombre = "Dude";

  add_sort(temprfc, tempnombre);
  temprfc = "AUDE010101R1";
  tempnombre = "Commander";
  add_sort(temprfc, tempnombre);
}

// print list
template<typename T>
void list<T>::print()
{
   node<T> *temp = m_head;
   if (!m_head)
   {
       cout << "List is empty" << endl;
   }
   else
   {
       while (temp)
       {
             temp->print();
             if (!temp->next)
                 cout << "NULL\n";

             temp = temp->next;
       }
   }
   cout << endl;
}

// search the list
template<typename T>
void list<T>::search(T data_)
{
  node<T> *temp=m_head;
  int cont=1;
  int cont2=0;

  while(temp)
  {
      if(strcmp(temp->data,data_[0]))
      {
            cout<<"Element found " << temp->data;
            cout << " in position: " << cont << endl;
            cont2++;
      }
      temp=temp->next;
      cont++;
  }
  if(cont2==0)
  {
      cout << "Element not found"<<endl;
  }
}

// ... delete by data
template<typename T>
void list<T>::del_by_data(T data_)
{
   node<T> *temp = m_head;
   node<T> *temp1 = m_head->next;

   int cont =0;
   if (m_head->data ==  data_)
   {
       m_head = temp->next;
   }
   else
   {
        while (temp1)
        {
            if (temp1->data ==  data_)
            {
                node<T> *aux_node = temp1;
                temp->next = temp1->next;
                delete aux_node;
                cont++;
                m_num_nodes--;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
            temp1 = temp1->next;
        }
   }
   if (cont == 0)
   {
       cout << "No data" << endl;
   }
}

// destroy the constructor
template<typename T>
list<T>::~list() {}

int main()
{
   list<char> list1;

   char element1[30];
   char element2[30];

   int dim, choice, pos;

   do{
          cout << "Select a choice.\n";
          cout << "1. Print list\n";
          cout << "2. Delete an element of the list\n";
          cout << "3. Search an element of the list\n";
          cout << "4. Exit\n";
          cin >> choice;

          switch(choice)
          {
                case 1:
                {
                    cout << "Printing list:\n";
                    list1.fill("1","2");
                    list1.print();
                    break;
                 }

                 case 2:
                 {
                    cout << "Element to delete: ";
                    cin >> element1;
                    list1.search(element1);
                    element1 = "";
                    break;
                 }

                case 3:
                {
                    cout << "Element to search: ";
                    cin >> element1;
                    list1.search(element1);
                    element1 = "";
                    break;
                }
          }
   }while(choice != 4);



  return 0;
}
```

The code doesn't compile, it marks errors like:

" error: prototype for ‘void list::fill(char*)’ does not match any in class ‘list’
 void list::fill(char rfc[30])
      ^
t3b.cpp:79:8: error: candidate is: void list::fill(char*, char*)
   void fill(char r[30],  char n[30]);"

Any ideas on how to fix it? Or any ideas on how to put 2 elements in a node using templates?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your declaration (prototype) of `list::fill()` doesn't match its corresponding definition. To be specific, you declared `fill()` to take two parameters but defined it with one.

Comment: A doubly linked list has 2 pointers, maybe labeled next and previous.  Your effort has one pointer.

Comment: It is trivial to have 2 items in a node.  Perhaps you meant to identify a relation between the two elements and the elements in next and previous?  What is your question?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, i have seen my error.

Comment: "All the examples that i have seen are only for 1 element of the template node, so i'm trying to put 2 elements in the template node" - the traditional way to do this is to put one element in the node that contains 2 values like: `struct twovals { int a; int b; };`. Then do `list<twovals> mylist;`

Answer (score 1):

Dude, you should really try to isolate the error a little bit before posting it. This is 500 lines of code, I had to copy and paste it all into an editor before I could even look at it.

When you declared fill, it had two arguments, when you defined it, it had one. Also, I would avoid arrays of characters for numerous reasons, instead use `std::string`.